# PHP array combine and sum for undefined array depth

Tags: php

I need to merge two arrays of undefined dimensions by summing the values of the matching keys (and if not matching -> append).

The following example is given as a JSON, but it is already converted as an array:

JSON 1:

```
{
  "profile_id": "1011:profile",
  "data":{
    "xp":50,
    "bananas":10
  }
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
  "data":{
    "bananas":20,
    "xp":200,
    "cars":3
  }
}
```

Combined:

```
{
  "data":{
    "xp":250,
    "bananas":30,
    "cars":3
  }
}
```

But the above example is not fixed, I can have the "xp" field as a sub-sub key.
Better said, I need to sum all overlapping keys, and append to the array all non-overlapping keys (merge), without having a fixed array depth. Like an array_merge() with sum if overlapping. Also, the order of the keys is undefined.

Thank you!

Comment: From what you've told - I doubt we can help you. Show us your your samples & code with samples of desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using array_merge() https://www.php.net/array_merge

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Comment: I think it's more like a combination of array_intersect_uassoc() and array_merge_recursive().